# How to pass a model when redirecting to another action in order to display the model errors in the redirected view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to display the validation errors of a new `@comment` on the `articles\view.html.erb` when it fails to persist a comment through the `comments#create`.

**TLDR**, I have created a blog using the [Getting Started](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) tutorial with rails 4.2.6 and ruby 2.2.3.

---

A blog has many **Articles** and each Article has many **Comments**.

Following the tutorial, the form for posting a new comment is in the `articles\view.html.erb` and it's persisted in the `comments#create`. After posting a new comment it redirects to the `articles#show` again.

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  validates :title, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5 }
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article
end
```

I use the same view - `articles/show.html.erb` - to display an **article**, its **comments** and post a **new comment**

```
<p><strong>Title:</strong><%= @article.title %></
<p><strong>Text:</strong><%= @article.text %></p>

<h2>Comments</h2>
<% @article.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <p><strong>Commenter:</strong><%= comment.commenter %></p>
  <p><strong>Comment:</strong><%= comment.body %></p>
<% end %>

<h2>Add a comment:</h2>
<%= form_for([@article, @article.comments.build]) do |f| %>
  <p><%= f.label :commenter %><br><%= f.text_field :commenter %></p>
  <p><%= f.label :body %><br><%= f.text_area :body %></p>
  <p><%= f.submit %></p>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_path(@article) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', articles_path %>
```

through the `articles_controller`

```
def show
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
end
```

and the `comments_controller` to post a **new comment**

```
def create
  @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
  @comment = @article.comments.create(comment_params)
  redirect_to article_path(@article)
end
```

It worked as expected :)

---

**Here is where my problems started...**

I decided to go further by adding some validation to the **Comment** model

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article   
  validates :commenter, presence: true
  validates :body, presence: true
end
```

and display the comment errors when it fails to save it.

First, I tried to display the errors trough the article model

```
<% if @article.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(@article.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this article from being saved:</h2>
    <ul><% @article.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %></ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Then I tried with a global var `@comment` in `articles_controller`

```
def show
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  @comment = @article.comments.build
end

<% if @comment.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(@comment.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
      this comment from being saved:</h2>
    <ul><% @comment.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %></ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

It didn't work too.

As far as I understand it doesn't work that way since when I submit a **new comment** I redirect to the article show action `redirect_to article_path(@article)` - either if it succeeded or not to save the new comment - thus a new comment instance is created, overriding the previous one with its errors.

My best solution was using the `flash` property with the error messages. It looks like this

`comments_controller`

```
def create
  @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
  @comment = @article.comments.create(comments_params)
  redirect_to article_path(@article), flash: {new_article_errors: @comments.errors.full_messages}
end
```

`articles/show.html.erb`

```
<% unless flash[:new_comment_errors].nil?  %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2>
      <%= pluralize(flash[:new_comment_errors].count, "error") %> prohibited this comment from begin saved:
    </h2>
    <ul>
      <% flash[:new_comment_errors].each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

But this isn't the best solution too. It displays the errors but loses the values already filled (the form is clear).

**Should I need to pass the @comment through the redirect_to?** Something like this

`comments_controller`

```
def create
  @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
  @comment = @article.comments.build(comments_params)

  if @comment.save
    redirect_to article_path(@article)
  else 
    redirect_to article_path(:comment => params[:comment] )
  end
end
```

`article_controller`

```
def show
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  @comment = @article.comments.build

  @comment.valid? if params[:comment]
end
```

**Now I'm getting the `No route matches` error. Should I create a new action that receives a `params[:comment]`? or editing the show route to receive it?**

I already read the [Nested model validation - errors don't show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12972112/nested-model-validation-errors-dont-show) but didn't help because they suggested to create the **new action** in the `comments_controller` and I don't want that (the **new post form** needs to be in the `article/show.html.erb`).

[Nested Model Form Part 1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1?autoplay=true) and [Nested Model Form Part 2](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2?autoplay=true) didn't help too.

Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nested model validation - errors don't show](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12972112/nested-model-validation-errors-dont-show)

Comment: Thanks @Vucko, I'll check that.

Comment: It's not a duplicated question @Vucko. I edited the question to add more information and to avoid possible duplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of redirecting to the `ArticlesController#show` method (which as you've discovered will cause all of your instance variables to be lost) you can, instead, render the show view.

```
if @comment.save
  redirect_to article_path(@article)
else 
  render :template => 'articles/show'
end
```

You already have `@template` and `@comment` instance variables, so they'll be used in the render.

Comment: I had been looking for something like this before but I didn't found it. I'll try it. Thanks for your time @SteveTurczyn =b

Comment: I entered a typo, fixed now, so if it doesn't work, check my example code again!